# Connecting os installed HD to another computer

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware, hard-drive

I have installed windows server 2008 on a system. I want to connect this 2008 server hard disk to different hardware configuration(another computer). Will it work without any flaw if connected to another system?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not likely unless the hardware configuration is identical.  If this is going into production, I'd highly recommend reinstalling Windows Server 2008 on the new computer.

Answer (score 1):

If the hardware is not identical or very similar, you will most likely have issues with the storage driver. You could image the drive and test it, or just install fresh on the new system.